# Реализация поиска по FK Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird

Мне нужно вывести название всех таблиц которые зависят друг от друга.
Таких таблиц 200 + зависимые.
Например, таблица Х имеет FK от Y и Y имеет FK от Z. То-есть поиск по FK.
Можно реализовать поиск FK из списка таблиц, а также из найденых таблиц?

Вот запрос который ищет названия для одной таблици (M_KONTRAH_GL):

```
SELECT
   master_relation_constraints.rdb$relation_name AS reference_table
FROM
   rdb$relation_constraints detail_relation_constraints
   JOIN rdb$index_segments detail_index_segments ON detail_relation_constraints.rdb$index_name = detail_index_segments.rdb$index_name 
   JOIN rdb$ref_constraints ON detail_relation_constraints.rdb$constraint_name = rdb$ref_constraints.rdb$constraint_name 
   JOIN rdb$relation_constraints master_relation_constraints ON rdb$ref_constraints.rdb$const_name_uq = master_relation_constraints.rdb$constraint_name
WHERE
   detail_relation_constraints.rdb$constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
   AND detail_relation_constraints.rdb$relation_name = 'M_KONTRAH_GL'
```

Comment: Так в чем вопрос, что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Герман Борисов, вопрос в том, как сделать поиск по нескольким таблицам, а также к найденым таблицам к первой.

Comment: Ну наверное убрать фильтр по имени таблицы, но добавить это имя в список полей результирующего набора...

Comment: Уберите `AND detail_relation_constraints.rdb$relation_name = 'M_KONTRAH_GL'` и получите все таблицы

Comment: БД имеет 2к таблиц, нужно указать несколько таблиц по которых вести поиск.

Comment: тогда замените равенство литералу на IN и список литералов.

Comment: @Akina, а как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    detail_relation_constraints.rdb$relation_name AS base_table,
    master_relation_constraints.rdb$relation_name AS reference_table
FROM
         rdb$relation_constraints detail_relation_constraints
    JOIN rdb$index_segments detail_index_segments ON detail_relation_constraints.rdb$index_name = detail_index_segments.rdb$index_name 
    JOIN rdb$ref_constraints ON detail_relation_constraints.rdb$constraint_name = rdb$ref_constraints.rdb$constraint_name 
    JOIN rdb$relation_constraints master_relation_constraints ON rdb$ref_constraints.rdb$const_name_uq = master_relation_constraints.rdb$constraint_name
WHERE
    detail_relation_constraints.rdb$constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND detail_relation_constraints.rdb$relation_name 
    IN ('table1','table2', .. ,'tableN')
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Огромное СПАСИБО!

Comment: Как я понял здесь реализовано поиск FK только по тем таблицам которые указаны в списке. А можно реализовать поиск FK из списка таблиц, а также из найденых таблиц?

Comment: Firebird 2.5 поддерживает рекурсивные CTE. Так что никаких противопоказаний.

Comment: можете пожалуйста помочь в написпании рекурсии?

Comment: Я - нет. Я уже лет 8 как к нему не подходил... а изучать заново лениво. Но лучше бы Вам задать этот вопрос как новый.